# Problem with loops not stopping in FL Studio 20

Tags: fl-studio

I'm having the problem that when I'm using a loop from the default folders, either in the channel rack or in the playlist, they won't stop when they are supposed to (they are present in a pattern but they are reproduced in all of them, or they are present in a part of the playlist and they are played in all the playlist as soon as they are turned on) and it's ruinning some of my songs. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to solve this?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what this question is asking, could you please supply a screenshot? I have a few potential theories to what this could be, but can not be entirely sure until I see what is happening. Also, what version of FL are you on?

Answer (score 2):

In the sampler window (accessed from the channel rack), deselect "use loop points".